# What is the T-SQL syntax to connect to another SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

"What is the T-SQL syntax to connect to another SQL Server?" so that I can just paste that in the top of the create script and F5 to run it and it would switch to the new server and run the create script.I dont want to use SP_addLinkedserver i.e. i dont want to link the server....I just want to Connect to that server..

Comment: have you had a chance to read: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2311/using-the-ssms-query-editor-in-sqlcmd-mode/

Comment: @AliRazeghi i dont want to use SQLCMD mode or addlinkedserver...i m creating a sp which will fire from central server and collect the data from multiple server...i just want query..

Comment: Hi, it's not so much to create a linked server, but to directly connect to another server in SSMS, I could test this but it seems possible.

Comment: @AliRazegh I am very new to sqlServer can you just pass me the query to connect to another server...

Comment: SSMS won't do what you want to do.  `USE [dbname]` will specify a database name on the same server, but it won't change the connection to a different server.  You could do something with powershell or batch files and sqlcmd.exe if you want an automated way to roll the same script out to a bunch of servers.  Otherwise, you can only do this with SSMS by changing the connection manually.  If you need to do this from within a sproc you've got no choice but to use linked servers.

Comment: The only way you can do this is one of the ways you have said you dont want to do it.  Use SQLCMD mode in SSMS and the :connect command in your script.

Comment: As Kent stated, you can just use :connect command in SSMS using SQLCMD mode OR you can go with Aarons answer.  Both are really good.  First you would enable SQLCMD mode from SSMS (query tab) and then do a  :CONNECT SERVER1
SELECT @@ServerName;
go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can kind of make up a linked server on the fly:

```
SELECT name
FROM OPENROWSET
(
  'SQLNCLI', 
  'Server=Server_Name\Instance_Name;UID=Username;PWD=Password;',
  'SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases;'
);
```

If you want Windows auth, just change the second line to:

```
  'Server=Server_Name\Instance_Name;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
```

First you need to set up the source server correctly:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
```

But you can't parameterize this etc., making it much less useful than a linked server or SQLCMD mode. So I suggest if all three of these options are not desirable for you, stop trying to catch fish with a toothpick, and do this *outside* of the database - PowerShell, etc. T-SQL was not really designed to function as an enterprise-wide information gatherer.

Comment: Best reply IMO,  if none of these really work well for you check out PowerShell scripts as Aaron recommended.  A lot of DBAs manage large groups of databases by using powershell heavily.  Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg313741.aspx for a good start.